# gcc Hello World on Ubuntu Touch: 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, gcc

I wanted to compile `printf("Hello World!\r\n");` on my Nexus and installed `sudo apt-get install gcc` but if I compile using

```
gcc -x c++ helloworld.cpp -lstdc++ -o helloworld
```

I get the error

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

It once did run but after reinstalling ubuntu it only shows missing cc1plus error and as I am no specialist (just wanted to run something like 
`system("service ssh stop");` or so) I want to ask what I can to to repair the gcc.

Comment: What is the name of your source code file, and how exactly are you trying to compile it? Pleased [edit] your question to include the complete command.

Comment: I compile `gcc -x c++ helloworld.cpp -lstdc++ -o helloworld` but I will not change that as it worked once.

Comment: So as I suspected you're telling `gcc` to treat the file as a C++ source file - in which case you will need to install `g++` as well as plain `gcc` (the giveaway is `exec 'cc1plus'`)

Comment: When I try to install `sudo apt-get install g++` I get the error `E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.` where I tried `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` and even `sudo apt autoremove`what did not help.

Comment: Well lack of space is something you will need to figure out yourself by uninstalling unneeded packages - if you have already installed `gcc` then the simplest thing would be to **not** try to compile it as `g++` (since it appears to be plain 'C' syntax) i.e. either rename your source code file to `hello.c` or use `gcc -x c` - *"I will not change that as it worked once"* is not really a good argument here, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, my lack of space really is another problem and I already tried the .c file extension successfully after my first answer, so thanks so far and may be I will open a new ask for the `space in /var/cache/apt/archives/` - problem I did google for days and not yet did find a solution (uninstalling packages makes crash my ubuntu and forces many hours of setting up all new...)

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
```

arises because by using `-x c++` and a `.cpp` filename suffix, you are telling `gcc` to treat your source code file as C++ rather than plain C, and do not have the `g++` compiler installed.

Since `printf("Hello World!\r\n");` does not use any C++ syntax elements, the simplest solution is to compile as plain C - either by renaming your file and omitting the `-x` directive:

```
gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld
```

or (if you want to keep the `.cpp` suffix), using `-x` to tell `gcc` to treat it as C regardless

```
gcc -x c helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

Note that in either case you will need to remove the `-lstdc++` directive since the C++ standard library won't be available (or required).

Answer (score 0):

install `build-essential`

```
c++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

you can

sudo rm -r /var/cache/*

Comment: Why `rm -r /var/cache/*`? What's that supposed to achieve?

Comment: if you cant answer selfstate about that It's bad.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. To clarify, I know *what* `rm -r /var/cache/*` does, but I would like to know *why* you find that effect desirable in this situation.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now: you're referring to OP's comment about the lack of space on `/var`. I didn't notice that comment before. You should probably make that clear to future readers so they don't start deleting their caches if they only suffer from the initial problem which is totally unrelated to the one outlined in the comments. Also, `rm -r /var/cache/*` doesn't just delete Apt caches and may only be a temporary solution for a more serious underlying problem.